# How to show phone's portrait layout in tablet irrespective of it's orientation WITH ViewBinding WITHOUT locking orientation?

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, landscape-portrait, android-viewbinding

I have a fragment called **ErrorFragment**.

I have different layout files to be shown on phone for portrait (**error_fragment_portrait_content.xml**) and landscape(**error_fragment_portrait_content.xml**) mode.

But I want to use the same layout (**phone's portrait layout**) in tablet mode irrespective of tablet's orientation.

Please note that I **don't want to lock the orientation**. I want orientation to be switched, but  layout to be shown should remain the same.

And I want to use the **ViewBinding** for my fragment.

I know a straightforward solution is to just copy the layout file **error_fragment.xml** from **res/layout/** folder to **res/layout-sw600dp**. But this is adding up to the apk size. I want to avoid this.

I tried another approach as well. This is the code snippet of my **error_fragment.xml**:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/error_fragment_content"
        layout="@layout/error_fragment_portrait_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In **res/layout/ folder**, I am including `layout="@layout/error_fragment_portrait_content"`

In **res/layout-land folder**, I am including `layout="@layout/error_fragment_landscape_content"`

In **res/layout-sw600dp** folder, I am including `layout="@layout/error_fragment_portrait_content"`

But the binding file generated for **ErrorFragment** (**ErrorFragmentBinding**) gets confused whether to create and instance of **ErrorFragmentPortraitContentBinding** or **ErrorFragmentLandscapeContentBinding**? It's generating an instance of **ViewDataBinding**. So getting a build error with this approach.

So, I want to know how can I achieve my desired results?

Comment: Try https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#layout

Comment: @CommonsWare but how does this work with ViewBinding?

Comment: I do not know that it does work with view binding. I suggested that you *try* [the documented approach for layout aliases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#layout) in hopes that it will solve your problem.